# ColdFusion .Net Integration Error: DotNetExtension not installed

Tags: .net, coldfusion, integration, coldfusion-10

I've been trying to get the .NET integration Service working correctly in my ColdFusion 10 environment, but despite uninstalls/re-installs/reboots/service restarts, it refuses to generate the proxy classes within ColdFusion.  I just upgraded the .NET Framework to 4.6, and according to Adobe's documentation, installing a new .NET Framework requires uninstalling/re-installing the CF .NET Service. [[1](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Installing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cdec18969-7ff1.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cdec18969-7fef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cdec18969-7ff1.html)]

The server has several ColdFusion instances running, so I installed the CF .NET Service as a standalone, and the service itself is running as Local System.

I've made sure that the `neo-dotnet.xml` file within each instance's `lib` folder contains the directory where I installed the .NET service, and the .NET dll I am using for the test is about as simple as it gets:

```
namespace DLLTest
{
    public class MyClass
    {
       public int Add(int x, int y)
        {
            return x + y;
        }
    }
}
```

The way I'm calling the .NET assembly is as follows:

```
<cfobject type=".NET" name="testDLL" class="DLLTest.MyClass" assembly="[Absolute_PATH]\DLLTest.dll')">
```

When the .cfm page is run, it creates the following stacktrace:

```
coldfusion.runtime.dotnet.Assembly$DotNetExtensionNotInstalledException:
DotNetExtension not installed. at
coldfusion.runtime.dotnet.Assembly.loadClass(Assembly.java:258) at
coldfusion.runtime.dotnet.Assembly.loadClass(Assembly.java:226) at
coldfusion.runtime.dotnet.DotNetProxyFactory.getProxy(DotNetProxyFactory.java:78)
at coldfusion.runtime.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:65) at
coldfusion.runtime.CFPage.createObjectProxy(CFPage.java:5785) at
coldfusion.tagext.lang.ObjectTag.doStartTag(ObjectTag.java:441) at
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2795) at
cfDLLTest2ecfm188311117.runPage([PATH_TO_FILE]\DLLTest.cfm:7) at
coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:244) at
coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:446) at
coldfusion.filter.CfincludeFilter.invoke(CfincludeFilter.java:65) at
coldfusion.filter.IpFilter.invoke(IpFilter.java:64) at
coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:451) at
coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48) at
coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40) at
coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:112) at
coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:94) at
coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28) at
coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38) at
coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:58) at
coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38) at
coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22) at
coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62) at
coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:219) at
coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) at
coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42) at
coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241) at
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208) at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) at
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501) at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) at
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) at
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950) at
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) at
org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve.invoke(JvmRouteBinderValve.java:218) at
org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve.invoke(ReplicationValve.java:333) at
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:422) at
org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:199) at
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607) at
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314) at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) at 
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) at
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Comment: I'm having this same issue except with CF 2016. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the .NET service to no avail...

Answer (score 0):

I received this same error after installing ColdFusion 2021 Enterprise edition on a test server. Code that worked previously on ColdFusion 2016 was throwing this error. After debugging this for a long time, the issue ended up being that the ColdFusion instance on my 2021 server didn't have the jnbridge folder. It was only located in the default "cfusion" instance's folder. To resolve the issue, I did the following:

1. Copied the "jnbridge" folder from cfusion to my instance's folder
2. Restarted the "ColdFusion 2021 .NET Service" Windows service
3. Restarted the "ColdFusion 2021 Application Server INSTANCE_NAME" Windows service